# Get first column of a row using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Markup

```
<TABLE id=tblRoleHdr>
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD style="WIDTH: 1%"><INPUT id=rptParent_chkRoleHdr_0 class=1 type=checkbox name=rptParent$ctl00$chkRoleHdr jQuery1323238445410="2"> </TD>
            <TD style="WIDTH: 50%"><INPUT id=rptParent_hidRoleID_0 value=1 type=hidden name=rptParent$ctl00$hidRoleID> <SPAN id=rptParent_lblRole_0>Admin</SPAN> </TD>
            <TD style="WIDTH: 1%"><INPUT id=rptParent_chkP1Hdr_0 class=Group1ColumnHdr1 type=checkbox name=rptParent$ctl00$chkP1Hdr group_role="1" jQuery1323238445410="4"> </TD>
            <TD style="WIDTH: 1%"><INPUT id=rptParent_chkP2Hdr_0 class=Group1ColumnHdr2 type=checkbox name=rptParent$ctl00$chkP2Hdr group_role="1" jQuery1323238445410="6"> </TD>
            <TD style="WIDTH: 1%"><INPUT id=rptParent_chkP3Hdr_0 class=Group1ColumnHdr3 type=checkbox name=rptParent$ctl00$chkP3Hdr group_role="1" jQuery1323238445410="8"> </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

jQuery

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () { ... });
```

Task

If I click on the check boxes having `class=GroupXColumnHdrY` where X and Y are numbers, I want to go to the first column of the row and retrieve the `class` of `rptParent_chkRoleHdr_0` check box. How can I do it using jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#tblRoleHdr').find('[type="checkbox"]').filter('[class^="Group"]').bind('click', function () {
    var the_class = $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(0).children().attr('class');
    //console.log(the_class);
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fFCEr/